# Temporary Procedure define variable issue

Tags: mysql

I'm trying out MySQL procedures for the first time, however I can't figure out how to define the variable @index_ids for the life of me. It really doesn't like the SET.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #indextemp
BEGIN
  SET @index_ids = (SELECT DISTINCT index_id FROM visibility_index_processing_queue WHERE process_id IS NOT NULL);
  SELECT @index_ids;
END
```

Comment: "It really doesn't like the SET" - you should elaborate on that. What error message are you getting or what behavior you see vs what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `CREATE PROCEDURE` syntax, not in setting variable. You just have to add parentheses after procedure name. Here's working sample

```
delimiter $
CREATE PROCEDURE indextemp()
BEGIN
  SET @index_ids = (SELECT DISTINCT index_id FROM visibility_index_processing_queue WHERE process_id IS NOT NULL);
  SELECT @index_ids;
END$
delimiter ;
```

Sometimes use of delimiter character in procedure body can cause problems too. That's why I set delimiter to `$` before creating procedure and revert it to default `;` after I'm done.

Also notice that I have removed `#` from your procedure name. In sql `#` is used to insert comments. If for some reason you really want to use it in your name you have to do it like that

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `#indextemp`()
```

Comment: Thanks this is progress, but it still errors if I try to use # in the procedure name to set it as a local temporary procedure

Comment: Nevermind, I think I'm looking at trying to do something impossible in mysql